# What would make a printk not show up immediately in dmesg?

Tags: c, ubuntu, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am making a Linux kernel module on Ubuntu 4.14.12.

My understanding of printk() is that it is guaranteed to output to console immediately before the next line of code is run, rather than having its output placed on a buffer that is eventually flushed at some point. Is this correct?

I was getting a crash that occurred several hundred lines after multiple printk calls whose output did not appear in dmesg using the -wH command or in dmesg sent through tee to a file which I read after rebooting.

Is there lag between the time a printk is sent to console and it shows up in dmesg that would allow my system to freeze up before I saw the output? Or is there something else occurring?

dmesg shows the printks in question after fixing the problematic line of code. The console log level was set higher than the console log level of the printks in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many layers between your module calls `printk(...)` and the output showing up on the console.

> My understanding of printk() is that it is guaranteed to output to console immediately before the next line of code is run, rather than having its output placed on a buffer that is eventually flushed at some point. Is this correct?

No, this is not correct. There is no "console" in `printk()` implementation and there shouldn't be any. There's always a buffer, many layers of buffers.  The line [1705 in printk.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.7/source/kernel/printk/printk.c#L1705) answers your question. The `printk_emit()` function uses a statically allocated buffer `static char textbuf[LOG_LINE_MAX];` and calls `vscnprintf(textbuf, sizeof(textbuf), ...)` on it to parse arguments. So it uses a buffer. I don't think it is possible to write a `printf` function without using an internal buffer, at least it's harder. And the `__log_buf` variable is a statically allocated buffer, an array of characters, and it *is* the kernel log buffer.

> Is there lag between the time a printk is sent to console and it shows up in dmesg that would allow my system to freeze up before I saw the output?

Yes? There's always a lag. I don't know how to define a "lag" (one milisecond? A second? One nanosecond?) but the assembly instructions behind `printk` function has to execute, then all the layers up until they are placed in [__log_buf](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.7/source/kernel/printk/printk.c#L293) static variable. Then `dmesg` which awaits on `read()` syscall is woken up I guess somewhere inside [console_unlock](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.7/source/kernel/printk/printk.c#L2233). After the wakeup `dmesg` will finally call [devkmsg_read()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.7/source/kernel/printk/printk.c#L671) function which will return the buffer. Then `dmesg()` will call `write()` syscall on stdout after it has received the data. Then `write()` kernel syscall will try to write something onto your screen - so the data has to go all the way through console drivers and display drivers and graphics drivers. There's always a lag. But it should be minimal.

> dmesg shows the printks in question after fixing the problematic line of code

Which just says that `dmesg` didn't get the output from kernel log. There is probably something else occurring. The simplest is `dmesg` process does not get cpu time, is blocked on reading syslog, your module executes inside with irq disabled, and so on.

Comment: Side note: a nice discussion on the matter recently happened @LKML: https://lwn.net/Articles/780556/

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation. It's good when I add '\n' at end of msg.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

The kernel ring buffer is line buffered, which means it's not flushed until it encounters a newline, so add newline `\n` to the end of msg.

`pr_info("Some message\n");`

Answer (score 0):

The printk messages are queued to a memory buffer and a user mode service has to receive the messages and out it to a file or the systemd-journal.